# C# - Linq select in list property by other property

Tags: c#, linq, casting

My response class

```
public class JSONResponse
{
    public int return{ get; set; }
    public string[] message{ get; set; }
    public Data data{ get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public Presence[] presences { get; set; }
}

public class Presence
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name{ get; set; }
    public Field[] fields { get; set; }
}

public class Field
{
    public string label{ get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

My new class

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public bool Temp{ get; set; }
}
```

Inside the json class I have the property Fields that have a couple of value (Label, Value)

I wish to cast into MyClass and set the Temp property getting the value property based on label value of Fields :

```
   MyClass myclass = JSONResponse.data.presences.Select(x => new MyClass()
    {
        Id = Convert.ToInt32(x.id),
        Name = x.name,
        Temp = x.fields.Where(a => a.label == "Label") // i want the value property
}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LINQ has a set of functions to map a list to a single entry of that list. I think the most correct option in your case is [`SingleOrDefault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault?view=net-5.0).

```cs
var result = JSONResponse.data.presences.Select(x => new MyClass()
{
  Id = Convert.ToInt32(x.id),
  Name = x.name,
  Temp = x.fields.SingleOrDefault(a => a.label == "Label")?.Value,
});
```

The reason I suggest `SingleOrDefault` over `FirstOrDefault` is that `SingleOrDefault` throws an exception when it finds multiple matches. By doing it like this you will get an Exception, not a possible incorrect value, when there are duplicate labels.

Answer (score 0):

Use `FirstOrDefault`

```
Temp = x.fields.FirstOrDefault(a => a.label == "Label")?.Value
```